# What tools are you using to validate models Javascript?

Tags: node.js, validation, sanitization

I am looking for the best solution to validate/sanitize the data i am passing between my front and nodejs back end.

I heard about a few options but none of them was widely used.

What are you guys using?

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a broad questions, and there are many modules for it.
I have personally used [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) a lot, mostly because it works well with HapiJs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you use it in the front end?

Comment: I haven't tried it tbh.
But I don't see why you can't